# How to get clickable text that invokes a function

Tags: button, emacs

Let's say I have the following text in the buffer

```
CMM-3:       Description
CMM-91:      Description 2
```

I want the CMM-XX to become clickable areas that invoke a custom function

```
(defun jira-ticket-view (&optional jira-ticket)
  "Open Jira Ticket Inside Emacs"
  (interactive)
  ....)
```

#### How this can be achieved in emacs/elisp?

Comment: Org mode is the first thing that comes to mind; You might consider checking the [source](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/ol.el#L1598) for their link handling.

Answer (score 8):

Create a new keymap, bind `mouse-1` to the function you want to call, and add the keymap to the link text as a text property.  Set `mouse-face` to `highlight` and add `help-echo` for extra user-friendliness - those take effect when the user hovers the mouse pointer over the text.

```
(defun my-function ()
  (interactive)
  (message "You've clicked the text!"))

(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key map [mouse-1] 'my-function)
  (insert "Foo: "
          (propertize "bar" 'keymap map 'mouse-face 'highlight 'help-echo "Click here!")
          "\n"))
```

See the section [Clickable text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html) in the elisp reference manual for more information.

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to get the clickable text mapping to pass one or more arguments to the function? If possible, I could then use one function for multiple clickable texts that pass different arguments to that same function, and the function itself could evaluate its argument(s) as part of its responses to the clicks.

Comment: @HippoMan There's `apply-partially`: `(apply-partially 'my-function "my-argument")` would return a function that calls `my-function` with `"my-argument"` as the first argument. Or perhaps the Button package (built-in to Emacs) could be suitable: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buttons.html The `action` function for a button gets called with the button itself as an argument.